# Getting Undefined index when trying to loop through an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I'm trying to loop through an associative array but getting an Undefined index error.

Below is the array.

```
{
    "first":{
        "name":"name 1",
        "products":[
            {
                "id":2,
                "product_id":123,
                "category_id":1
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                 "product_id":"456"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to loop through this like

```
foreach ($array as $category => $products) {
    echo $category;
    foreach ($products['products'] as $product) {
        echo $product->id;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting a

```
Undefined index: products
```

How can I loop through the products array?

Comment: Use `$array = json_decode($array, TRUE);` before looping

Comment: What's the definition of `$array`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `$products['products']` to `$products->products` because 
`$products` is **object** not **array**.

```
$test='{"first":{"name":"name 1","products":[
{"id":2,"product_id":123,"category_id":1},{"id":3,"product_id":"456"}
]}}';
echo "<pre>";
$array=json_decode($test);
foreach($array as $category => $products){
    foreach($products->products as $product){
        echo $product->id."<br/>";
    }                
}
```

[demo.....](http://phpio.net/s/1guz)

Comment: The $test is already in array. So I tried json_decode(json_encode($my_array)); and then ran the array in foreach as you said. But I'm getting Undefined property: stdClass::$products

Comment: if your data is json then convert array and if array then remove json_decode.

Comment: The data is array and on trying by not passing it through json_decode I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: foreach($array as $category => $products){
            foreach($products->products as $product){
                echo $product->id;
           }                
     }
 
And I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object"